# Concurrent futures in python doesn't wait for processes to finish

Tags: python, concurrency, multiple-processes

I've got a function, main(), that generates 4 processes, and starts executes them eventually, but it loops over this whole block of code once it begins several times. What I *want* to have it do I think is apparent; print "hello1", execute the processes (and therefore the print statements), and then print "hello2"

What am I doing wrong? Would also be open to a solution that uses multiprocessing.Process() if that's easier, but I've had the same issue there as well.

```
def funcy(c):
    print("Hi " + str(c))
    for e in range(1000):
        e = e
    return c*2

print("hello1")

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        f = [1,2,3,4]
        results = executor.map(funcy,f)

        for result in results:
            print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

print("hello2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is that the for loop is indented within the `with` context manager for the `concurrent.futures` call.  Also, the `print("hello1")` seems out of place.  The  `print("hello2")` needs to be indented.

I think the below edit is what you're looking for...maybe...

```
import concurrent.futures

def funcy(c):
    print("Hi " + str(c))
    for e in range(1000):
        e = e
    return c*2

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        f = [1,2,3,4]
        results = executor.map(funcy,f)

    for result in results:
        print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("hello1")

    main()

    print("hello2")
```